# XCode auto code generation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm new IOS and XCode. I added some bottuns to my IPhone app and now I want to add to them functionality.
I found [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH7-SW4).

The problem is that when I drag the button to ViewControler.h it bounces back.

Please advice.
Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

press `Ctrl button + drag the your button` to viewController.h then `"Insert Outlet and Outlet Collection"` will be appeared. After that you remove your finger on mouse you will get `Outlet` box regarding connection. It has connection, Name, Type properties. I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

You can make UIButtons or any UIControl one of two ways

1. By Programmatically
2. By .xib file

I think you are talking about the second method.

In the second method you take UIButtons in class:

```
@interface className : UIViewController{ 

  IBOutlet UIButton *buttonName;

}
```

Now you will have to click on the .xib file and then you have to select a file below responder; after that open connection connection inspector. Now you can drag and drop UIButtons on the .xib file and establish a link between displayed UIButton in connection inspector and .xib's UIBUtton.

Comment: This does not answer the question.